# Brew install git fails

Tags: macos, git, gcc, homebrew

I want to install git with homebrew. I had MacPorts installed, which I removed from my iMac. I also removed homebrew completely, and reinstalled it with `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"`.

After I ran `brew doctor` I had to delete (I only moved them) some libs inside `/usr/local/lib`. After that I fixed the `$PATH` var in my `.profile`, so that the `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` are overwriting the normal bin dir.

Now I wanted to install git with `brew install git`. It fetched the content, and begins building git. But during the build, it fails with the message

```
~$ brew install git
spo==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.12.4.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-1.7.12.4.tar.gz
==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.12.4 CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 CFLAGS=-Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4.1 -mmacosx-version
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git-credential-store] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Writing perl.mak for Git

Error: git did not build
Logs: /Users/23tux/Library/Logs/Homebrew/git/
Help: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
      https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11481
      https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14423
      https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/14585
```

I looked into the `/Users/23tux/Library/Logs/Homebrew/git/` and it says, that there are undefined symbols. Here is the output:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2  -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4.1 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -I. -DPRECOMPOSE_UNICODE -DUSE_ST_TIMESPEC -DNO_GETTEXT  -DHAVE_DEV_TTY -DSHA1_HEADER='<openssl/sha.h>'  -DNO_MEMMEM -DSHELL_PATH='"/bin/sh"' -o git-credential-store -L/usr/local/lib  credential-store.o libgit.a xdiff/lib.a  -lz  -liconv  -lcrypto -lssl 
Undefined symbols:
  "_strbuf_addstr_urlencode", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_strbuf_getline", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_strbuf_release", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_credential_clear", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_usage_with_options", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_credential_from_url", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_credential_read", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_commit_lock_file", referenced from:
      _rewrite_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_die_errno", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
      _rewrite_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_credential_match", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_strbuf_slopbuf", referenced from:
      _parse_credential_file in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_expand_user_path", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_parse_options", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_write_or_die", referenced from:
      _print_line in credential-store.o
  "_die", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_strbuf_addf", referenced from:
      _main in credential-store.o
  "_hold_lock_file_for_update", referenced from:
      _rewrite_credential_file in credential-store.o
  "_strbuf_grow", referenced from:
      _print_line in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
      _main in credential-store.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [git-credential-store] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Writing perl.mak for Git

HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.3
HEAD: (none)
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.6.8-i386
Xcode: 3.2.6
X11: 2.3.6 => /usr/X11
```

(the output is much longer, I only included the last few lines, where the error happened).

I googled a lot, but can't find any solution. Is this because of some broken things with MacPorts (I know, they don't like each other)? Or how can I fix that?

**EDIT**

I just found out, that when I'm running `brew doctor`, I get this output:

```
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
You must: brew install git
Warning: An outdated version of Git was detected in your PATH.
Git 1.6.6 or newer is required to perform checkouts over HTTP from GitHub.
Please upgrade: brew upgrade git
```

When I run `brew upgrade git` I get `Error: git not installed`. I searched my PATH var for any binary of git (or something else), but can't find anything.

I think this means, that somewhere there is git stuff left, and it conflicts with the new install. Am I right?

Comment: So `which git` does not return a result? Xcode (or just the command line tools) is/are installed?

Comment: ``which git`` doesn't return a value, XCode is installed (3.2.6). ``which gcc`` returns ``/usr/bin/gcc`` and ``which g++`` returns ``/usr/bin/g++``

Comment: I found some notes, that installing gettext would solve the problem, unfort. it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to install git with homebrew in that case. 'Cause I didn't want to waste so much time, I installed the whole rvm, ruby, git stuff with the Rails Installer from here http://railsinstaller.org/. Then it worked with homebrew